# Upload and show image in liferay portlet with icefaces

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet, icefaces

I have this XHTML code:

```
<h:form>
<ice:graphicImage value="#{uploadImage.byteArrayImage}" 
                  rendered="#{uploadImage.byteArrayImage!=null}"/>
<ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryComp" 
               label="File Entry" 
               relativePath="uploaded"
               useOriginalFilename="true" 
               fileEntryListener="#{uploadImage.customValidator}"/> 
<h:commandButton value="Upload Image" / >
<h:message for="fileEntryComp" />
</h:form>
```

and this java method for upload image:

```
    public void customValidator(FileEntryEvent entryEvent) throws IOException {    
        FileEntryResults results = ((FileEntry) entryEvent.getComponent()).getResults();
        for (FileEntryResults.FileInfo file : results.getFiles()) {
            if (file.isSaved()) {
                if (!file.getContentType().equals("image/png")) {
                    file.updateStatus(new FileEntryStatus() {    
                        @Override
                        public boolean isSuccess() {
                            return false;
                        }    
                        @Override
                        public FacesMessage getFacesMessage(
                                FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent fileEntry, FileEntryResults.FileInfo fi) {
                            return new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    "Only PNG files can be uploaded. Your upload has been cancelled.",
                                    "Only PNG files can be uploaded. Your upload has been cancelled.");
                        }
                    },
                            true, true);
                } else {            
                    this.byteArrayImage = readIntoByteArray(new FileInputStream(file.getFile()));                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and i need upload and show image on the page, but it doent work a i don't know why. Thanks for answer.

Comment: The Liferay Faces Project (which I am a part of) has some example code which does this in the [Icefaces3 Users Portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.2.x/demos/portal/icefaces3-users-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/resource). Perhaps that may help.

Comment: You should also take a look at the [`getSelectedUserPortraitURL()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/3.2.x/demos/portal/icefaces3-users-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/bean/UsersModelBean.java#L98) method from the same portlet.